# Accessing DataContext properties in View

Tags: c, wpf, mvvm

I'm hoping someone can give me a kick in the right direction, I'm currently learning WPF and MVVM - let's say its not been plain sailing. Basically I'm trying to access the properties of DataContext and bind them to a property  in my view. I'll be completely honest, I've got myself in a bit of a tangle.

When the user clicks the button in question it fires the code below.

```
 private void OnReceiptClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialogBox = new DisplayReceiptView(((CheckMemberViewModel) this.DataContext).ReceiptViewModel);
        dialogBox.ShowDialog();
    }
```

My CheckMemberViewModel currently holds the 'Person' property I'm after, and at this stage DataContext is populated as expected.

The code behind my DisplayReceiptView  looks like the following:

```
 public DisplayReceiptView(ReceiptViewModel context) : this()
    {
        this.DataContext = context;
    }
```

Once again everything seems correct, and finally in my XAML I have

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=Person}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">Name:</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Person.Forename}"></TextBox>
      </Grid>
```

Unfortunately no matter what I've done, and I think where I'm up to at the moment is the closest I've been, the data doesn't seem to bind. Below is my ViewModel code for the properties

```
       private Person _person;
        public Person Person
    {
        get { return _person; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _person)
            {
                _person = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Person");
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Person.Forename}"></TextBox>
```

This is wrong as you are already bound to Person

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Forename}"></TextBox>
```

Is all you need

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Forename, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

Will save changes to the source and retrieve changes, but of course you will need to save context changes to make them permanent

Comment: Agreed - generally you don't bind to A.B.C.D, where these represent a chain of properties and sub properties. You set the data source to A.B.C and then bind to D - the last property in the chain. The notification is only on that property.